# Spark Streaming Java

Tags: java, spark-streaming

I am very new to Spark Streaming. I have a stream of data like the following:

```
{"client":"Lighting","command":"Lighting State","name":"A","state":"Green"}
{"client":"Lighting","command":"Lighting State","name":"B","state":"Red"}
```

I am getting this data continuously after every 2 seconds. I have a hashmap that should collect the "name" as key and keep adding 2 to the value part, thus its a running total. I am able to get the lines separated from Red lines but I don't understand how to proceed from there. The Green lines I get is using the following code:

```
JavaDStream<String> lines = 
    jssc.textFileStream("/Users/me/Downloads/kafka_2.8.0-0.8.0/bin/output.txt");

JavaDStream<String> lightLines = lines.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(String messages) {
            return messages.contains("Lighting");
        }
    });

JavaDStream<String> lightsOnLines = lightLines.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call(String messages) {
        return messages.contains("Green");
    }
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you aren't parsing the JSON and extracting relevant data from it?

Comment: What is the question? It's not clear at the moment.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I need the processing to be fast and so I thought if I deal with JSON instead of using the inherent transformations provided by Spark, it would make it a little slow. But I don't really understand how to apply reduceByKey or any other transformations. Any guide in that direction would be really helpful!

Comment: @maasg: I need to increment the count of light in the hashmap each time it shows a Green in state. If the state is Red I dont do anything. My hashmap is holding running totals for all the lights present in the incoming data. For example: Hahsmap after the current input => A:2, B:0.  Similarly if I receive the same input again, Hashmap becomes like => A:4, B:0. I hope it is clear now. :-)

Comment: @user114  I'm still confused: I don't see any hashmap in the code provided

Comment: You want to count for whole job or batch or window? Please elaborate.